# Google Script Libraries Not Working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm assuming I'm skipping a step here, but I can't seem to figure out how to use libraries. Here are the steps.

## Library:

Create New Project

-Name it "test"

-function myFunction() { return "HELLO"; }

-publish

-file->project properties->get project key

### Main Program

-Add Library (Resources->Libraries->Add key->Name it test, Select Dev (for simplicity)

-Code: var mytest = test.myFunction();

### Result:

In console, I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The Library set up dialog looks like this:

[image: Library Dialog]

Did you type 'test' into the **Identifier** field?

Comment: Well.  Maybe it's a problem with Google?  I don't know.  You might want to check out the issue tracker, and see if anyone else is having a problem.  [Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)  Or make a post in the Apps Script Group.

Comment: Link to group:   [Apps Script Community](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: I feel as though that is unlikely. It is pretty much the most simple of libraries, and some more complex ones work completely fine.

Comment: I'm guessing it might be something specific to that one Apps Script file.  You might try starting over again with a new file.